# show image after textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to show an image next to about 6 textboxes...I dont want to use div tags as these vary in position with IE/firefox etc. Is there a simple way to display a small image next to a textbox? such as using :after in css?

Cheers

Comment: Do you mean: `[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [img]`? And it can wrap to next line too?

Comment: Its for validation..such as showing a green tick or red cross if it passes or not, so using javascript I want it to show it next to the textbox, rather than having to find the position

Comment: So it is one image for the 6 boxes and not one image for it right?

Comment: yep, either a cross or tick for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery is easy

```
$(".textbox").after('<img src="validation-mark.jpg" />');
```

Here the HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="textbox"></input>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to show/hide the validation marks, maybe you can have them all declared in the HTML next to you text boxes like this

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1"></input><img src="validation-mark.jpg" />
<input type="text" id="textbox2"></input><img src="validation-mark.jpg" />
<input type="text" id="textbox3"></input><img src="validation-mark.jpg" />
```

And show them or hide them with this jQuery code:

```
$("#textbox1+img").hide();
$("#textbox1+img").show();
```

The jQuery selector `#textbox1+img` means "the image after the element with ID: textbox1"

Comment: Thanks that is easier than I thought!
how would I hide/show the image in javascript?

Comment: I put this just to answer the question but I recommend to use divs, Blaenk suggestion is pretty good to solve your browser compatibility issues

Comment: thanks...could you give me an example how to use the hide function within javascript? I havent used jquery before..

Comment: Oh, this solution just work using jquery. It's really easy to learn and I'm sure you'd love it. Check out 'getting started with jquery' http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Answer (score 1):

The style:

```
label.tbimg {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(http://sstatic.net/so/img/vote-accepted-on.png); center right no-repeat;
    padding-right: 30px;   /*icon width*/
}
label.noimg {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 30px;   /*icon width*/
}
```

The HTML:

```
<label class="tbimg"><input type="text" class="textbox"></input></label>
<label class="noimg"><input type="text" class="textbox"></input></label>
<label class="tbimg"><input type="text" class="textbox"></input></label>
<label class="tbimg"><input type="text" class="textbox"></input></label>
<label class="noimg"><input type="text" class="textbox"></input></label>
<label class="tbimg"><input type="text" class="textbox"></input></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by div's vary in position on each browser? If you're referring to padding and the like, you can try using a [reset stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset).

Comment: such as the image displays in-line with textbox in firefox, but in IE it shows about 3 lines below.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure a reset stylesheet will solve a few of those spacing inconsistencies between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not placing it inside a td?(I guess this is the simplest)

e.g.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="t1"></td>
<td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="t2"></td>
<td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="t3"></td>
<td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="t4"></td>
<td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="t5"></td>
<td><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="t6"></td>
<td><img src="myimg.jpg" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If needed (if the requirement is like that), create that at runtime.